# How can I find P[X ≥ 2Y] from the joint pdf?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X and Y have the joint pdf   $f(x,y) =xye^{−x−y}$   $(x > 0,y > 0)$

Find $P[X ≥ 2Y]$.

I really don't know what can I do for this...

Comment: By definition, $$P(X\ge 2Y)=\iint_{x\ge 2y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$P(X\geq 2Y)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{X\geq2Y}=\int\int\mathbf[x\geq2y]f(x,y)dxdy$$where $[x\geq2y]$ is a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if $x\geq 2y$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with

$$\int_0^\infty\int_{2y}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy.$$

That is

$$\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}\bigg(\int_{2y}^\infty xe^{-x}dx\bigg)dy$$

Compute the integral in () then see where it goes?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{2y}^{\infty} xye^{-x-y}dxdy = \frac{7}{27}$$